# Spring boot API getting error 404 on Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, postman

I'm learning how to use Spring boot now, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why my POST requests are not getting through.

I'm using Java 17 , VS code, and POSTMAN for the requests.

This is a straight forward demo for me only to learn the basics of spring boot.
I dont have an actual DB in place, nor do I have a frontend up and running.

I am only trying to recieve a status 200 for the request.

Any help would be great.

my request is POST "localhost:8080/api/v1/person"

Body:  `{"name": "John"}`

console

```
2023-02-27T21:55:37.208+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 10664 (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\°≥Θσ≡σ· ∞⌠°σΘΘ≈ΦΘφ\Backend\demo\target\classes started by ASUS in C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\°≥Θσ≡σ· ∞⌠°σΘΘ≈ΦΘφ\Backend\demo)
2023-02-27T21:55:37.214+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-27T21:55:37.944+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-27T21:55:37.955+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-27T21:55:37.956+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-02-27T21:55:38.057+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-27T21:55:38.058+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 802 ms
2023-02-27T21:55:38.344+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-27T21:55:38.352+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.44 seconds (process running for 1.756)
2023-02-27T21:55:44.377+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-27T21:55:44.377+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-27T21:55:44.378+02:00  INFO 10664 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Person

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Person {
          
      private final UUID id;
      private final String name;

      public Person(@JsonProperty("id") UUID id,
      @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
                  this.id = id;
                  this.name = name;
      }

      public UUID getId() {
                  return id;
      }

      public String getName() {
                  return name;
      }

          
}
```

PersonService

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.dao.PersonDao;
import com.example.demo.model.Person;

@Service
public class PersonService {

      private final PersonDao personDao;

      @Autowired
      public PersonService(@Qualifier("fakeDao") PersonDao personDao) {
                  this.personDao = personDao;
      }
      
      public int addPerson(Person person) {
                  return personDao.insertPerson(person);
      }


}
```

PersonController

```
package com.example.demo.api;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Person;
import com.example.demo.service.PersonService;

@RequestMapping("/api/v1/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {
      
      private final PersonService personService;

      @Autowired
      public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
                  this.personService = personService;
      }

      @PostMapping
      public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
                  personService.addPerson(person);
      } 
}
```

Edit: adding the spring boot application

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can’t see anything obvious. Can you please add the class with the SpringBootApplication annotation? This might be a package structure issue.

Comment: I edited the main post with the SpringBootApplication annotation. Any thoughts?

Comment: status code is 404 or 415 ?

Comment: I am getting status 404

Comment: Check to see if there is an empty space at the end of the URL that you use for the POST request. Everything should work with the code that you posted, just make sure postman creates the request properly

Comment: I did check, but the problem persists. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Could it be something with the Tomcat or Maven?

Answer (score 0):

check your *.yml config key: server.servlet.context-path

edit: tomcat additional check items

Tomcat also needs to check deployment -> application context

Comment: Can you please explain what do mean? I am fairly new to Spring boot. Thanks!

Comment: if your server.servlet.context-path value  is 'example', url : http://localhost:8080/example/api/v1/person

Comment: if your 'deployment -> application context' value is 'example-demo', url : http://localhost:8080/example-demo/api/v1/person

Comment: Check the configuration file of your project and the specific configuration of your project and then Tomcat, I just give an example

Comment: Novices are not very recommended to use VS code as a development tool. It is recommended to try more complete software, such as Idea, Eclipse, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! , it says above: Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ' '. So I guess it is ok no?

Comment: Can you put your code and related configuration in a github repositories?

Comment: https://github.com/sapirtalk/demo

Comment: I can't come up with your question, my request is successful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).